# How do I use a list<string> to loop a process in cmd?

Tags: c#, list, loops, netsh

I have a netsh profiler that I want to get detailed information for each loop found.

```
        private void wifiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show profiles";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.Start();
        //* Read the output (or the error)
        string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox3.Text = output;
        cmd.WaitForExit();




        // output would be set by earlier code
        var Output = textBox3.Text;

        var regex = new Regex(@"All User Profile[\s]+: (.*)");
        var resultList = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(Output))
        {
            resultList.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
        }
        textBox4.Text = string.Join(", ", resultList);
```

The code above works, below I want to take the list and run the results through CMD again to get the detailed results.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
        {
        Process cmd2 = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show profiles name=" resultList(0) + " key=clear";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.Start();
        //* Read the output (or the error)
        string output2 = cmd2.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox5.Text = output2;
        cmd.WaitForExit();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `resultList[i]`?  What error are you getting?  What prevents your code from working?

Comment: @David I could kiss you haha, you are totally right man. That and I mislabeled my second set for the loop as cmd and not cmd2. Looks like it is working for the most part.

Comment: @code I used (0) instead of (i)

Answer (score 0):

Im a good and used a 0 instead of the i placeholder. Also, mislabeled my second cmd run and forgot to update to cmd2, therefore the previous command line would overlap itself and break.

```
   private void wifiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show profiles";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.Start();
        //* Read the output (or the error)
        string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox3.Text = output;
        cmd.WaitForExit();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);


        // output would be set by earlier code
        var Output = textBox3.Text;

        var regex = new Regex(@"All User Profile[\s]+: (.*)");
        var resultList = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(Output))
        {
            resultList.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
        }
        textBox4.Text = string.Join(", ", resultList);


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
        {
            Process cmd2 = new Process();
            cmd2.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            cmd2.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show profiles name=" + resultList[i] + " key=clear";
            cmd2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmd2.Start();
            //* Read the output (or the error)
            string output2 = cmd2.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            textBox5.Text = output2;
            cmd2.WaitForExit();
        }
}
```